# Magento 2 how to set permission in production mode

Tags: error, cache, permissions, magento-2.1.9, production-mode

I have successfully completed all issues in **developer mode**,
and now I moved to **production mode**, every thing is working fine
but when I am try to **`cache clear`** from **`admin panel`** , **frontend permission are missing**.

Comment: what do you mean **frontend permission are missing**? css not loaded or showing error output?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146749)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146749)